# The meaning of “They were a few days into ....”

Tags: phrase-meaning

I was reading a passage from ielts book to improve my reading skill, but there is a sentence I couldn’t figure out what idea it is expressing because the grammar sounds unusual to me, here is the sentence:

> “On 24 July they were a few days into their descent of the valley.”

I am not sure the exact meaning of the phrase “they were a few days into”, does it mean they spent few days? I would be very grateful if someone can help me make it clear.

Comment: They simply had been descending into the valley for a couple of days.

Comment: It means they had been descending for a few of days, but also their descent is not complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AHD defines the idiomatic expression ***[be into](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+into)***:

> To have reached some point in an ongoing process or measure of time: *I was halfway into this book when I lost interest in it. We were well into April before the snow stopped falling.*

A few days into the descent, that is,  the descent started a few days ago.